# When I open XAMPP and click the start MySQL button, it gives me an error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

> ```
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 1524
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240207  7:40:50
> 2024-02-07  7:40:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 9504
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300306
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 300315; transaction id 170
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240219  7:49:18
> 2024-02-19  7:49:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 14056
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=368953
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 368962; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  7:37:26 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 6216
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 368971; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:16 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 6524
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 368980; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240226  8:04:42
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:04:42 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 9436
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 368989; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240226  8:05:43
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:05:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 1620
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 368998; transaction id 356
> ```

More

> ```
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240226  8:08:59
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:08:59 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 5356
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 369007; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 1732
> Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x5556)
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 369007 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 369016 in the ib_logfiles!
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 369016; transaction id 356
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240226  8:15:57
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
> 2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> ```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You do what it says in the message. Off topic.

Comment: Try to locate what has been FAILED and search a reason/solution on the the issue.

Comment: What is crashing MariaDB hard about 9 minutes after startup? Did something happen before this was occurring that was significant? Consider a restore from backup.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the error logs, did you see this line:

2024-02-26  8:15:20 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files

Have you ran:

aria_chk -r

This also might be the cause:

2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2024-02-26  8:15:57 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Found this on stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198735/could-not-open-mysql-plugin-table-some-plugins-may-be-not-loaded